# Is is possible to create setup package for website as we do for windows Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to create a setup package for A website as do for a windows Application?

Is it possible to create a setup package such that it will deploy the website in IIS by itself?

I heard that it is possible to create such setup file. Please let me know if it is true. If true , how to do it

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Consider using **Web Deploy**

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

It is nicely integrated with Visual Studio projects and you can create a package which you can than deploy to multiple machines.

> Web Deploy enables you to package your Web application content,
>   configuration, databases and any other artifacts like registry, GAC
>   assemblies etc., which can be used for storage or redeployment. If the
>   package needs to be redeployed to a different environment,
>   configuration values within the package can be parameterized during
>   deployment without requiring modifications to the packages themselves.
>   Once created, these packages can be deployed using Web Deploy cmdline
>   or IIS Manager without requiring administrative privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Red-gate also has a free product that can automate this for you:

http://www.red-gate.com/delivery/deployment-manager/

Answer (score 1):

Consider using **Windows Xml Installer**

[WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possile.

How exactly depends on your requirements and VS version.

With out-of-the-box VS2010 (and earlier)  you can create a Web Setup project. In VS2012 this option is gone.

For large (largish) projects you should look at IIS packages. In VS2012 the starting point is under the Project properties, Package/Publish tab .

And there are 3rd party solutions for smaller/different projects. Already mentioned here.